On Lipschitz Matrix-valued Functions
In the context of matrix-valued functions, i.e. $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, we say that $f$ is Lipschitz if $\exists L>0$, s.t.
$$
\|f(x)-f(y)\|_F \leq L\|x-y\|_2
$$
with $\|\cdot\|_F$ the Frobenius matrix norm. Is this definition reasonable?
In particular, my question is motivated by a Lipschitz requirement on the Jacobian $J_g$ of some function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, in such setting the Lipschitz requirement reads as
$$
\|J_g(x)-J_g(y)\|_F \leq L\|x-y\|_2
$$
in such case, what this requirement entails on the function $g$?

Yes, it's reasonable. Since all norms are equivalent on a finite-dimensional space, the Lipschitz property doesn't depend on which norms you take in your definition.  Of course, the Lipschitz constant (i.e. the infimum of all $L$ for which the inequality is true) does depend on which norms you take.  What does the requirement entail about $g$?  Well, it's a bit stronger than $C^1$ and a bit weaker than $C^2$ with bounded second derivatives.

Thanks for elucidating! Going on with my problem I found out that a Lipschitz requirement on the Jacobian pseudoinverse $J_g^+(x)$ pops out. Obviously this leads to something more stringent in terms of requirements on $g$. I was thinking if this could possibly be related to the operator norm of  $J_g^+(x)$ and thus to the least singular value of $J_g(x)$. (p.s. I am struggling to find some material that deals with such problems)
